# unable to join the tables in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

> so I am trying to join two tables  but getting an error message saying "Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "bella_beat" at [14:22]

````
SELECT 
id ,
LightlyActiveMinutes AS light_active_mins,
FairlyActiveMinutes AS fairl_active_mins,
VeryActiveMinutes AS very_active_mins,
sleep_tracker.TotalMinutesAsleep AS total_sleep_mins,
sleep_tracker.TotalTimeInBed AS total_bedtime_mins

FROM 
my-project-1-325906.bella_beat.activity_tracker 
JOIN 
my-project-1-325906.bella_beat.sleep_tracker
ON 
my-project-1-325906.bella_beat.activity_tracker.id = my-project-1-325906.bella_beat.sleep_tracker.id```
````

Comment: put backticks around table references - like `\`my-project-1-325906.bella_beat.activity_tracker\``   Also - you can just use `USING (id)` for ON clause

Comment: tried but not working..there is a trifle issue that I am overlooking most of the time I guess